# Do I need to reinstall PHP on Mac to get newly installed features?

Tags: php, mac-osx, installation

I admit that I am a bit spoiled by the Windows installer.  Anyway, I have mac os x leopard server and am trying to get gettext to work.  I had trouble with pear but put the include for pear in the /etc/php.ini file.  GetText seems different.  I don't know where to point to in php.ini or if that's how to get it to "see" it.  I installed GetText from source ./configure, make, etc. Do I have to reinstall PHP on Mac to get new stuff to work with --with?  thank you.

edit:  just wanted to ask a different way than the body above.  With PHP, if you want a new feature, do you have to reinstall the whole thing?  How does PHP know about the new library installs?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [MacPorts](http://macports.org/install.php) to install whatever extensions you need and keep them up-to-date.

This also saves you from having Apple come along and replace your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I can't directly address your question, but I would consider using an installer such as provided by [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or by using the [BitNami MAMP Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/mampstack).

Answer (score 0):

Wile using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) is probably the easiest solution, it's not an answer to your question. The php.ini can define and load [php extensions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/extensions.php). Things like gettext are linked into php's source during build time and php will have to be recompiled from source to make use of your new libraries.

Comment: does that mean I need to redownload php, redo ./configure and make, the whole thing?

Comment: You have to compile php from source with your new gettext in the ./configure command. Or use macports to install php with gettext built in.